# Flatten Nested List to Flat List Containing Strings

Tags: python, string, list, tabs, nested-lists

Making the dictionary:

I have a set of 50 text files, all set up with a first header row, the first column being gene names, and the remaining columns being values for each gene. I also have an official gene list text file. I want to use the official gene name list to build a dictionary, then iterate over the files, determine if the gene name for each line matches the gene name in the dictionary, and if it does, append the dictionary value with the additional values from the experimental file.

So the experimental file looks like this:

```
Gene_ORF    ExpA    ExpB
geneA   12      34
geneB   42      10
geneC   42      10
```

The official gene list looks like this:

```
Gene_ORF    
geneA   
geneC
```

I used the following code to iterate over all the files in a directory and make the dictionary:

```
dict = {}

df_list_all = [ fn for fn in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if fn.endswith("results.txt") ]

with open("gene_orf.txt", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            name = line.split('\n')[0]
            dict[name]= []

for each in df_list_all:
    with open(each, 'r') as g:
        for each in g:
            gene = each.split('\t')[0]
            data = each.rstrip('\n').split('\t')[1:]
            if gene in dict:
                dict[gene].append(data)
```

So the dictionary looks like this:

```
{ 'Gene_ORF': [['ExpA', 'ExpB'], ['ExpC']], 'geneA': [['12, '34'], ['42']]...}
```

I used the following code to convert the dictionary into a nested list:

```
nestedList = [ ]
for key, val in dict.items():
    nestedList.append(f"{key} \t {val} \n")
```

That resulted in a nested list that is composed like the following:

```
"Gene_ORF \t [['ExpA', 'ExpB'], ['ExpC']] \n GeneA \t [['12', '34'], ['42']] \n"
```

I am trying to flatten the nested list, but am running it to issues dealing with the strings. I've tried several things, including:

```
flatList = ' '.join([data for ele in nestedList for data in ele])
```

and

```
flatList = []
for elem in nestedList:
    flatList.extend(elem)
```

But every time, I get a result like this:

```
O R F _ G e n e   \t.  [ [ ' E x p A ' , ' E x p B ' ] , [ ' E x p C ' ] ]   \n
```

I'd like the flatList to look like this:

```
Gene_ORF \t ExpA \t ExpB \t ExpC
GeneA \t 12 \t 34 \t 42
```

Because I'd like to write all that to a final so it looks like this:

```
Gene_ORF    ExpA    ExpB    ExpC
GeneA       12      34      42
```

I'd really appreciate any help or advice you have.

EDIT:  Edited to indicate how I made the nested list in the first place.

Comment: is this a `list` or a `string`?

Comment: try ' '.join without a space between the quotes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
The input you give is not a legal Python object, so we're not sure what you're actually using.

Comment: I made a nested list (I think anyway) from a dictionary, where the key was Gene_Orf or GeneA and the value was a nested list. I put them into a nested list using thinking it would be easier to get them how I need to export the values to a text file.

Comment: The reason it's printing like that is what you've posted at the top is a string, I'm assuming wrapped in double quotes. `str.join` will not work on non-string objects unless they are converted to strings, which you don't do. How are you building this string? What does it actually look like? Can you add both of those things to the question?

Comment: Ok, can you also include how you build that dictionary? I think you have an XY problem. It looks like you are trying to create a dataframe or some sort of space-delimited file, so starting at the very beginning might help identify the issue at hand

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited the post to show how I made the dictionary and the nested list.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to solve my problem and wanted to post the solution in case it helps anyone else out in the future.

I used the following code to write the dictionary keys and values to a list, wherein the values are separated by tabs, then sort the list and write it all to a file (my ultimate goal):

```
combined = [ ]
for key, val in dict.items():

    #this should flatten the nested list that makes up the values
    val2 = [val for sublist in combo[key] for val in sublist] 

    #separate the flattened list of values with tabs
    val3 = "\t".join(val2) 

    #write each key and value to a list with new lines at the end of the values
    combined.append(f"{key}\t{val3}\n") 

    #sort the list starting at the second row, leaving the header first
    combined[1:] = sorted(combined[1:]) 

#write each line to a text file
with open("final.txt", 'w') as f:
    for each in combined:
        f.write(each)
```

I'm sure there are other ways I could improve this code, but it seems to be working for me.